# How can I asynchronously handle stream events in Node.js while preserving order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, eventemitter

I have a stream with some events:

```
    responseStream.on('end', resolve)
    responseStream.on('error', reject)
    responseStream.on('data', doStuff)
```

And

```
const doStuff = async (chunk) => {
  return await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(chunk.toString())
    resolve()
  }, Math.random() * 1000))
}
```

What I want to do is keep the order that events are emitted in. But that doesn't happen since the handler takes different time. What's the best way to preserve the order of the emitted events?

Comment: What do you mean preserve the order of the events?  The events occur in their own natural order.  You don't control that.  And making `doStuff()` async is of no use at all because the stream doesn't pay any attention to the returned promise from that function.

Comment: Right. So I can’t control the order that events are emitted in. But given that order, I want to execute my listener sequentially

Comment: Your listener will be called sequentially.  What are you really saying here?  That you want  the 2nd `data` event to not get called until all your asynchronous stuff in the 1st `data` event is done?  And, that you don't want the `end` event to get called until and previous `data` events are done?  Can you show some REAL code that you're trying to execute rather than this pseudo-code?

Comment: That's correct - exactly that. The 2nd `data` event should not execute until the 1st is done and so on until the `end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an async-aware queue or a promise chain in order to queue up events as they come in and hold them until the previous asynchronous event handlers are done.  I started implementing it as a queue, but then decided that a promise chain is probably easier.

Here's an idea for how to do it:

```
class eventQueue {
    constructor(emitter, errorHandler) {
        this.emitter = emitter;
        this.errorHandler = errorHandler;
        this.chain = Promise.resolve();
        this.err = null;
        this.emitter.on('error', this.processError.bind(this));
    }
    processError(err) {
        // only ever call the errorHandler once
        if (this.err) return;
        this.err = err;
        this.errorHandler(err);
    }
    on(event, handler) {
        this.emitter.on(event, (...args) => {
            // wait for previous events to be done before running this one
            // and put the new end of the chain in this.chain
            this.chain = this.chain.then(() => {
                // skip any queued handlers once we've received an error
                if (this.err) return;
                // now that the chain has gotten to us, call our event  handler
                return handler(...args);
            }).catch(err => {
                this.processError(err);
                throw err;
            });
        });
        return this;
    }
}
```

Each incoming event is added onto a promise chain and won't get executed until all previous events have resolved any promise they returned.

Then, in your pseudo-code, you'd do something like this:

```
let queue = new eventQueue(responseStream, reject);

queue.on('end', resolve);
queue.on('data', doStuff);

const doStuff = (chunk) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(chunk.toString())
    resolve()
  }, Math.random() * 1000))
}
```

Note, the eventQueue, already  has a built-in listener for the `error` event so you don't need to explicitly set one.  It will call the errorHandler you pass to the constructor.  Any promise that rejects will also cause that same errorHandler to be called.  Once the errorHandler is called, no more event handlers will be called.  The queue will be locked in an error state.

Comment: @Shamoon - Is this the concept you were looking for?